# I would like to rewrite a wordpress url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

tried to rewrite a wordpress url address

**I need to convert this link:**
http://localhost/wordpress/landing-page?name=coursename

**to this one:**
http://localhost/wordpress/landing-page/coursename

I tried to change the htacces with a plugin, but nothing happened,this is my htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^landing-page/(.+)$ /wordpress/landing-page?id=$matches[1] [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


# This is my line

RewriteRule ^landing-page/([0-9]+)$ landing-page?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

i don't know what i am doing wrong, could someone help me to solve and show me how to do it.
Thanks!

Comment: Your rules are in the wrong order. However, this is unlikely to work with WordPress, since WP looks at the requested URL, not the rewritten URL (if it did then it would always see `index.php`, not the URL the user requested). You need to configure this in WordPress itself, not `.htaccess`. The [WordPress SE site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) might be a better fit for this question.

Comment: And does that `$matches[1]` make any sense in an apache configuration file?